# Show products count in WooCommerce product category widget sidebar

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, count, widget, categories

I am able to display the categories in the side bar using WooCommerce category widget:

[image]

But I need to display also the number of product in each product category, i.e.

[image]

How do I do this in WooCommerce?

Answer (score 1):

in /wp-admin/widgets.php

in the `product category` widget, check `Show product counts`

[image]

Comment: How can you modify the WooCommerce product category count in widget sidebar? I wish to remove the brackets from the category count and style the count number. Any thoughts will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please post a new question for this issue

Comment: Thanks Elia, I have done so here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838556/how-to-modify-and-style-woocommerce-product-category-count-number-in-sidebar-wid