# How to modify and style WooCommerce product category count NUMBER in sidebar widget

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Ok, so I have found the way to modify the 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html' for the categories count in the home page like so in the functions.php and style it in css. Here is an image to show what I mean:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', 'filter_woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', 10, 2);

function filter_woocommerce_subcategory_count_html($mark_class_count, $category)
{
    $mark_class_count = ' <mark class="count">' . $category->count . '</mark>';
    return $mark_class_count;
}
```

[image]

But, I cant find a way to do the same thing for the product category count number in the product page sidebar:

[image]

We have the categories and the count number to the right for each.
I want to remove the brackets and style the count number.

I have tried crawling the net for examples, but I cant find anything specific to the sidebar category list.

Is this possible?

If anyone has any ideas where I can find a solution to target this particular issue, it will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this hook in your function.php file in theme folder

```
add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', 'update_count_output' );
function update_count_output($output) {
    return preg_replace('/\<span class\=\"count\"\>\((\d+)\)\<\/span\>/', '<span class="count">$1</span>', $output);
}
```

Then you can style the count number using CSS

Comment: Ahh, excellent. I just looked now in the WP Codex for this hook, though I would not have known how to do this off the top of my head. Would this be the only way to properly filter this list in functions.php? Thanks so much for this, you made my day!

Comment: Okay, so this is more specific to do with WordPress then WooCommerce.

Comment: Woocommerce use the `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/walkers/class-wc-product-cat-list-walker.php` for rendering Product cat list. I found only this way to change output. Another way is to edit html with javascript

Comment: Vkuter, I found a similar example from a similar earlier question that does the same thing, but in less code: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88545/how-to-remove-the-parentheses-from-the-category-widget I don't know which is better/more efficient? I am pretty green with php :/